# how to set textbox value to hidden field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

I have a GridView and at the bottom is a button were the user can add notes. Pressing this button shows a pop up where the user can enter their note. 
I need the system to remember the text of the note, so when the pop up closes and the user then clicks on the save button, it will save the text from the note into the database.

Code for the note:

```
<div id="divAddEditNote" class="dvdraggable">
    <input id="txtCurrentNoOfNotes" runat="server" style="display:none" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfNoteID" runat="server" />
        <table>
        <tro>
            <td <%= Company.Current.StyleTheme %> class="tdPreviewHeader">
                <span id="spAddEditNote" ></span> Note
                <a onclick="CloseAddEditNote()" title="Close" class="previewClose"></a>
            </td>                                        
        </tro>
        <tr>
            <td class="tblAddDetail" >
                <asp:TextBox TextMode ="MultiLine" runat="server" id="txtMCENote" rows="50" CssClass="mceEditor" style="width:100%;"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpNoteContent" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine"  runat="server" id="txtNote" rows="50" style="width:100%;display:none;"></asp:TextBox> 
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>                                      
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tblAddDetail">
                <a ID="btnCreateNote" onclick="CloseAddNote()" runat="server" style="float:left" class="btnSaveSmall" ></a>
                <a title="Close" onclick="CloseAddEditNote()" style="float:left;" class="btnCancelSmall">Cancel</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

At the bottom of this note pop up is a save button or a cancel button. When the save button is clicked I need to remember the value from the textbox.
I tried setting the textbox to the hidden field in the onclick method:

```
function CloseAddNote() {
        $("#<%= hfNoteID.ClientID %>").val = $('#<%= txtNote.ClientID %>');
        $("#divAddEditNote").fadeOut(300);
    }
```

Then in the method that saves everything to the database I was trying to call the hidden field 
protected void btnUpdateCVRT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        txtNote.Text = hfNoteID.ToString();
        ... rest of code to save to database
}

But `hfNoteID` keeps coming in as blank. How do I save what the user entered in the textbox to the hidden field? And stop the hidden field from going to a blank value when the notes pop up closes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - right now you're setting the value to a control/element, not to its text content. And [the set should be in the parens](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_set), not as an equal, I believe, for JQuery. It's a little counterintuitive.

```
$("#<%= hfNoteID.ClientID %>").val($('#<%= txtNote.ClientID %>').val());
```